# Как дать пользователю Telegram-бота несколько варинтов ввода тектса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Немного подправил код бота. Даты прописаны в формате `3.09`. Если ввести `03.09` или `03/09`, то выдаётся ошибка. Как дать пользователю такие варианты?

```
 def func(message):
    try:
        send = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(send))
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER_")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    try:
        send = message.text
        if message.text == send:
            data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(send))
            bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
```

Comment: Про проверку `send = message.text` и `if message.text == send:` вам уже в предыдущем вопросе написали, что это бессмысленно. По поводу ошибки - укажите конкретную ошибку, которую выводит Python.

Answer (score 0):

ответ:

```
  send = str(message.text)

        if send[0] == "0" and send:
            send = send[1::]
```